# GIT Daily/Hourly commit changes in folder

Tags: git, git-bash, git-gui

I am absolute newbie in all this GIT thing, I'm using GUI since I am too newbie for Bash.

I have a bunch of folders where I have created my GITs inside via GUI. Also I put .ignore file inside so I can track only files that I want. My question is, is there a way to make GIT track changes and auto commit for example every 60 minutes, so when I open GIT GUI master history I can see all changes done for that hour/day/week and when are they done. I want to track it this way because those are text files, and I have other people working on them via notepad/other text editors, they are not using GIT so they commit changes them selfs.
If anyone can help me with this I would like you too provide me step by step guide because I am new in this.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best Regards

Comment: Will multiple people be editing the same file? If so, any automation will have to consider how to pull the latest changes periodically, deal with merge conflicts etc. It might work out easier to write a quick cheat-sheet on git for the people editing the files instead.

Comment: No, they wont edit the same file. At least not in a same time. This GIT thing working perfectly at the moment, but I am committing it manually as often as I can. That's the reason why I want to make it work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In case of RHEL you can use crontab. Use "*/1 * * *  /home/username/test.sh" this for repeating the task every 1 hour.

Make a test.sh file in the folder you want to commit and write git commit command in the file. Give the absolute path in place of /home/username.

Comment: If I do this, do I need to have open GIT in that specific folder for this to work?